# Mojo::XMLRPC::Message::Response to Mojolicious JSON

Tags: perl, xml-rpc, mojolicious

I have an XML-RPC response, but I'm struggling to return it as a JSON using [`Mojo::XMLRPC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::XMLRPC). I appreciate your guidance.

```perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::XMLRPC qw[decode_xmlrpc];
#use XMLRPC::Fast;

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $xml = <<~'XML';
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <methodResponse>
      <params>
        <param>
          <value>
            <struct>
              <member>
                <name>myarray</name>
                <value>
                  <array>
                    <data>
                      <value>
                        <struct>
                          <member>
                            <name>bob</name>
                            <value>
                              <boolean>0</boolean>
                            </value>
                          </member>
                          <member>
                            <name>alice</name>
                            <value>
                              <i4>1</i4>
                            </value>
                          </member>
                        </struct>
                      </value>
                    </data>
                  </array>
                </value>
              </member>
            </struct>
          </value>
        </param>
      </params>
    </methodResponse>
    XML
    
    $c->render(json => decode_xmlrpc($xml));
};

app->start;
```

Comment: *"I'm struggling to return it as a JSON"* What error message do you get?

Comment: @HåkonHægland- the worst kind: `null` !  `XMLRPC::Fast` response gets converted to JSON, but I'd like to use `Mojo::XMLRPC` to get booleans in JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::XMLRPC the `decode_xmlrpc()` and `from_xmlrpc()` methods return a `Mojo::XMLRPC::Message` object containing the result. Looking at that module's source code https://metacpan.org/release/JBERGER/Mojo-XMLRPC-0.06/source/lib/Mojo/XMLRPC/Message.pm shows that it has a `parameters` method. So you could try the following:

```
$c->render(json => decode_xmlrpc($xml)->parameters);
```